# How to read a 2-channel audio file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, channel, audio-processing

When I read an audio file with `[y, Fs] = wavread(filename)`, it returns an Nx2 matrix. What are the meanings of these "channels"? Are they left & right? And if so, how should I combine them? I would have averaged them but an external code uses `x(:,1)` and I couldn't understand why.

So how can I read this signal correctly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, it's left and right. `x(:,1)` is just one channel (left, I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis Mendo is right. I was unable to find this information in `doc wavread` but if you check out `doc sound` it documents that `x(:,1)` is the left and `x(:,2)` is the right channel.

If you are using a recent version of matlab, conciser switching to `audioread`

In many cases the left channel is used because you may experience strange effects when mixing stereo channels. The phase-shift differs for each frequency and some frequency may get lost when averaging. Especially when analysing sound properties, use only one channel.